# ProGuard obfuscate package name with -keeppackagenames

Tags: obfuscation, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate com.google.gson.Gson to com.google.a.Gson.

I use `-keeppackagenames !com.google.gson.**` but it does not seem to work. My mappings.txt still includes:

`com.google.gson.Gson -> com.google.gson.Gson`.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some -keep option in your configuration is keeping the entire class name com.google.gson.Gson. This always includes the package name. There are no options to keep class names but obfuscate their package names; it just doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: But, there are cases where it is useful. Simply put, one wants to keep the class name, let say because of reflection and obfuscate the package.